# Put value from an array to another array specific column

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to put values from an array to another array on a specific column.

The context is to see which user was logged at some date.
The Array1 contains the date and the Array2 contains the information about the users.

Array1:

```
Date
06/01/2022 12:00:00
06/01/2022 12:00:02
06/01/2022 12:00:03
```

Array2:

```
IP             Users       DateHour
192.168.1.1    Snake       
192.168.1.3    Mario
192.168.1.4    John Doe
```

I need to append the DateHour column **(Array2)** dynamically with the date from the Date column **(Array1)**

Everytime i'm trying with a for loop or a foreach loop it don't append correctly and I don't understand why.

Here is an exemple of what I've done:

```
for ($i=0 ; $i -lt $Array1.Count; $i++){
    for ($y=0 ; $y -lt $Array2.Count; $y++){
    $Array2.Datehour[$y] += $Array1.Date[$i]
}
}
```

From my understanding, the **Array2.Datehour** column will append, but it take long to finish and nothing appear.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: This can be done with a for loop but the thing to note is that there seem to be no correlation between the two arrays. How do you know `$arr1[0]` correlates with `$arr2[0]` ?

Comment: Because it comming from two different files that is linked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the two arrays are *aligned* (index `N` of the first array corresponds to index `N` in the second array), you only need 1 `for` loop:

```
for($i = 0; $i -lt $array1.Count; $i++){
  $array2[$i].Datehour = $array1[$i]
}
```

Note that we index into `$array2`, not `$array2.Datehour` - the latter is a "synthetic array" made up of enumerated property values, and assigning to it won't modify the underlying array item.

Comment: Wow thanks, it work!